# what is the number of unused pointers in a complete binary tree of depth 5?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

According to me, the answer should be 32. But in various texts, it is given ad 16.
I am not able to find how it can be 16.

Comment: Is your book (incorrectly) counting the depth of the root node as 1?

Comment: I think you are misquoting 'various texts'

Answer (score 1):

Well *at* the 5th level it is 16. However, if you consider that each of the nodes has 2 unused nodes, it becomes 32 (at the 6th level). You would be correct, depending on how the original question was phrased.

Answer (score 0):

Complete binary tree means we count only left side leaf nodes. So it's unused leaf nodes(pointers) are 16.

But in case of an extended binary tree, we must take both sides left and right leaf nodes(pointers) which means there are 32.

So the ans = 16.